# Ormlite: How to use the offset method after where method?

Tags: android, ormlite

I am pretty new to Android and Ormlite. Currently, I am getting dao that could return a news List and I want to search the news List by type and page. The codes are like:

```
NewsItems = NewsItemDao.queryBuilder().where.eq("type",type).offset(0).limit(5).query;
```

First, I will get a list from eq method. Then I want the first to fifth news items. The above codes do not work, what should I do? Thanks.

Comment: How do they "not work"?  What results are you getting?

Comment: Also, note that the javadocs recommend that you specify an `orderBy(...)` otherwise you might get some strange ordering: http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/stmt/QueryBuilder.html#offset(java.lang.Long)

Comment: I guess the offset method has to follow straight to the queryBuilder() instead of eq(). And thank you for your suggestion about the ordering.

Answer (score 0):

For future readers, this is how you can use `offset() and limit()` with `where()` in `ormilte`.

```
   List<YourDomain> someList = yourDao.queryBuilder().orderBy(COL_CATEGORY, false).offset(start).limit(noOfRows).where().eq(COL_CATEGORY, category).query();
```

`public static final String COL_CATEGORY = "category";`

`COL_CATEGORY` is column name in the table.

this will return the list of `YourDomain` entries from database starting from `offset(value)` upto this `limit(value)` number of rows.

you need to pass value of `int` type to `offset(int) and limit(int)` in older version of ormlite. But in current version `4.48` of ormlite this is deprecated and now you need to pass value of `Long` type to `offset(long) and limit(long)`